# Can I get a list of method parameters in Java

Tags: java, reflection

---

I'm writing a *ton* of boilerplate like this. I feel like there has to be a better way. What I'm looking for is getting the new Object[] automatically from the method call. Something like Reflection.getCurrentMethodCall().getArgumentsAsList().toArray(), but I'm not sure what keywords I should be looking for

Thanks!

```
[ ... 50 identical methods ... ]
                @Override
            public int get_ProxyFactoryMapping(PointerByReference factoryMapping) {
                Function f = Function.getFunction(vTable[48], Function.ALT_CONVENTION);
                return f.invokeInt(new Object[]{getInterface(), factoryMapping});
            }

            @Override
            public int GetPropertyProgrammaticName(int property, PointerByReference name) {
                Function f = Function.getFunction(vTable[49], Function.ALT_CONVENTION);
                return f.invokeInt(new Object[]{getInterface(), property, name});
            }

            @Override
            public int GetPatternProgrammaticName(int pattern, PointerByReference name) {
                Function f = Function.getFunction(vTable[50], Function.ALT_CONVENTION);
                return f.invokeInt(new Object[]{getInterface(), pattern, name});
            }
            @Override
            public int GetPatternProgrammaticName(0..n arguments) {
                Function f = Function.getFunction(vTable[running index], Function.ALT_CONVENTION);
                return f.invokeInt(new Object[]{getInterface(), the same arguments as this object was called with});
            }
[ ... 150 identical methods ... ]
```

Comment: Please edit your question and show three more boilerplate methods, so we can see the pattern.  Are you overriding all those methods because you must?  Can you change the design of the class and its inheritance?

Comment: @Override
                public int GetPatternProgrammaticName([0..n parameters]) {
                    Function f = Function.getFunction(vTable[index], Function.ALT_CONVENTION);
                    return f.invokeInt(new Object[]{getInterface(), [the same     parameters]});
                }

Can't change the design much, this is a bridge between a Java interface and a legacy vTable object. We grab the appropriate function pointer from the vTable and call it with the functions given to the bridge.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [java.lang.reflect.Proxy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) and [java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/InvocationHandler.html)?

Basically you implement the `InvocationHandler` interface, which has one single method `invoke` that can give you what you want:

```
Object invoke(Object proxy, // the proxy object
              Method method, // the method called
              Object[] args) // the argument list
       throws Throwable
```

Then you pass an instance of the handler to `Proxy` class to get a proxy object (Code copied from Java Doc):

```
Foo f = (Foo) Proxy.newProxyInstance(Foo.class.getClassLoader(),
                                      new Class[] { Foo.class },
                                      handler);
```

Where `Foo` is a interface.